# Solution of trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry

Let $S_n$ be the solution of the equation: $\sin x \cdot \sin 2x \cdot ... \cdot \sin nx = 1$

$S_{100} = \: ?$

I have found that $ S_1 = \left\{\frac{\pi }{2}+2k\pi | k\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$.

The correct answer is $S_{100} = \emptyset$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sin x\cdot\sin 2x=1$ then it means (as $-1\leq\sin \alpha \leq1$) $$\sin x=\sin 2x=1 \text{ or } \sin x=\sin 2x=-1$$

We know that $$\sin \alpha=\pm1\iff \alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}+\pi k, k\in\mathbb Z$$

So if $x$ satisfies $\sin x\cdot\sin 2x=1$, it has to verify one of these sets of conditions:

$$\begin{cases} x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k_1  \\ 2x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k_2 \end{cases}, \qquad \begin{cases} x=\frac{\pi}{2}+(2\pi+1) k_1  \\ 2x=\frac{\pi}{2}+(2\pi+1) k_2 \end{cases},  \qquad k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb Z$$

But this is impossible, since an $x$ satisfying $x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k_1$ would also satisfy

$$2x=\pi+4\pi k_1=(4k_1+1)\pi$$

so it can't be an integer multiple of $2\pi$ plus $\frac\pi2$. The same goes for the second case.

That shows that any number $x$ cannot verify $\sin x=\sin 2x=\pm1$. In particular, it cannot verify
$\sin x=\sin 2x=\cdots=\sin 100x=\pm1$.

Comment: I think the cases should be taken separately (for 1 and -1), because for $k_1 = 0$ and $k_2 = 1$ the system is not valid, but aside of that, I understood, thank you !

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 2):

Since the left hand side is equal to one and $-1<=\sin(kx)<=1$, then all of the $\sin(kx)$ should be $\pm1$. Imagine $sin(x)=\pm1$. Either way, the $\cos(x)=0$

So $\sin(2x) = 2*\sin(x)*\cos(x) = 0$. So This statement can never be true.

Answer (score 1):

Note that all of your sines must be in the range $[-1,1]$. Therefore, the only numbers with inverses (that could multiply to 1) can be the answers of sine. However, we can, with ease, show that $\sin x \cdot \sin 2x$ must not equal 1, and since it has no inverse, the equality cannot possibly hold. The solutions to $\sin x = 1$ is $\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n, n \in \Bbb Z$ and to $\sin x = -1$ is $\frac{3\pi}{2} + \pi n, n \in \Bbb Z$. Therefore, we must have that either $\sin \pi = 1$ to multiply to 1 (we get rid of the $\pi n$ because sine and cosine are periodic) which can't be true, or $\sin 3\pi = -1$ to multiply to 1, which is also not true. Therefore, there are no solutions that multiply to 1 or -1 for $\sin x \cdot \sin 2x$, and so the product can not be 1.